# Exception: Service invoked too many times for one day: premium urlfetch. - Google Sheets Script / Maps API

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-places-api

Beginner coder here so be gentle!

I have managed to create a script that searches a customer list for latidtude longitude address and  company name (so I can confirm that the search result is the same as my list). The script worked as intended yesterday but I keep getting this error today: **Exception: Service invoked too many times for one day: premium urlfetch. (line 20).**

From what I can find of answers I need to implement a cache of some sorts, but Im not entirely sure how as I can't find a tutorial that I understand completely.

This is my script: it searches the A-column by entering the function call in column B.

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Custom Menu')
      .addItem('Find Address', 'findAddress')
      .addToUi();
}

function findAddress() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = range.getValues();
  var API_KEY = "INSER SPI KEY HERE";
  
  for (var i = 1; i < values.length; i++) { // Start from the second row
    var address = values[i][0]; // Get the address from column A
    var url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=" 
              + encodeURIComponent(address) 
              + "&key=" + API_KEY;
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
    var data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
    if (data.status == "OK") {
      var location = data.results[0].geometry.location;
      var lat = location.lat;
      var lng = location.lng;
      values[i][1] = lat; // Set the latitude in column B
      values[i][2] = lng; // Set the longitude in column B
      var place_id = data.results[0].place_id;
      var details_url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?place_id=" 
                        + place_id 
                        + "&fields=name,formatted_address,photo,rating,opening_hours&key=" + API_KEY;
      var details_response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(details_url);
      var details_data = JSON.parse(details_response.getContentText());
      if (details_data.status == "OK") {
        values[i][3] = details_data.result.name; // Set the name in column B
        values[i][4] = details_data.result.formatted_address; // Set the address in column B
      } else {
        return "Not found, correct customer name?"
        Logger.log("Details request failed: " + details_data.status);
        throw "Some error message that tells the user what error occurred and why it occurred?";
      }
    } else {
      return "Not found. Have you rund script from custom menu?"
      throw "Some results were not found, are you sure the cpany names are correct?";
      Logger.log("Geocoding request failed: " + data.status);
    }
  }
  
  range.setValues(values); // Write the updated values back to the sheet
}
```

I am also not completely familiar with how to call a function, do I need the onOpen part for the beginning of the script, seems a little cumbersome to have to run the script from there?

Comment: Do you have many searches upon many different addresses?

Comment: Yes around 2-300 customers

Comment: And how many distinct addresses they may query for (approximately)?

Comment: If you add more customers you rerun the entire script? If so just check if the data is already in the sheet, if so skip the fetch.

Comment: Don't use it as a custom function just use it as a standard script that runs from a  menu or a trigger.

Comment: @Cooper ah ok makes sense, I also figured out that using only the customer name and nothing else to help narrow down the result had the script running way too many requests.